# Regex: match fullstop and one word in python

Tags: python, regex

I am new to regex. I wish to write a regex which matches a '.' followed by a whitespace followed by a word(which does not contain whitespace.

For example, in the string "The sound of cracking. Splintering. A shape appears, in ice.", the regex should extract ". Splintering" and ". A".

Comment: & what have you tried so far to fulfill your wish?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please take a [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and visit the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) in order to find information about how to ask a good question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
import re
input = 'The sound of cracking. Splintering. A shape appears, in ice.'
print re.findall("(\.\s+[a-zA-Z]+)", input)
```

Output: `['. Splintering', '. A']`

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
(\.\s\w+)
```

Matches:

> . Splintering
>
> . A

[See it in action.](http://regex101.com/r/zS5wF5)