# How to add newline after every characters like ” .[xxx] “ in a string in python

Tags: python, regex

I have the following string :

```
It reported the proportion of the edits made from America was 51% for the Wikipedia, and 25% for the simple Wikipedia.[142] The Wikimedia Foundation hopes to increase the number in the Global South to 37% by 2015.[143]
```

I am trying to replace every characters lik this `.[xxx]`  with `.[xxx] \n`;

x are digits here

I am taking help from different stalk overflow answers; one such is :

[Python insert a line break in a string after character "X"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38888714/python-insert-a-line-break-in-a-string-after-character-x)

[Regex: match fullstop and one word in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22247359/regex-match-fullstop-and-one-word-in-python)

```
import re
str = "It reported the proportion of the edits made from America was 51% 
for the Wikipedia, and 25% for the simple Wikipedia.[142] The Wikimedia 
Foundation hopes to increase the number in the Global South to 37% by 
2015.[143] "
x = re.sub("\.\[[0-9]{2,5}\]\s", "\.\[[0-9]{2,5}\]\s\n",str)
print(x)
```

I expect the following output:

```
It reported the proportion of the edits made from America was 51% for the Wikipedia, and 25% for the simple Wikipedia.[142]                          
The Wikimedia Foundation hopes to increase the number in the Global South to 37% by 2015.[143]”
```

But I am getting:

```
It reported the proportion of the edits made from America was 51% for the Wikipedia, and 25% for the simple Wikipedia\\.\[[0-9]{2,5}\]\s   The Wikimedia Foundation hopes to increase the number in the Global South to 37% by 2015\\.\[[0-9]{2,5}\]\s
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use capturing groups and back-referrences in `re.sub`. You also don't need to escape the replacement string (**[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/RzN4mV/1)**):

```
import re
s = '''It reported the proportion of the edits made from America was 51% for the Wikipedia, and 25% for the simple Wikipedia.[142] The Wikimedia Foundation hopes to increase the number in the Global South to 37% by 2015.[143] '''
x = re.sub(r'\.\[([0-9]{2,5})\]\s', r'.[\1] \n', s)
print(x)
```

Prints:

```
It reported the proportion of the edits made from America was 51% for the Wikipedia, and 25% for the simple Wikipedia.[142] 
The Wikimedia Foundation hopes to increase the number in the Global South to 37% by 2015.[143]
```

Comment: What is r'.[\1] \n' exactly doing? Please Explain.

Comment: @AlmightyHeathcliff `\1` is reference to first capturing group, in this case `([0-9]{2,5})`

Comment: Thank you; I would like to know why the code is adding a new line after the word **Wikimedia**. I would like to have this:                                                                                                              
> The Wikimedia Foundation hopes to increase the number in the Global South to 37% by 2015.[143]”

Comment: @Noor becauise of formatting of input data. I updated my answer.

Comment: @AndrejKesely , I used the regular expression which  \1 is referencing, It then prints the regular expression. Aren't these two things supposed to be same?

Comment: @AlmightyHeathcliff No, its not same when you use regular expression in replacement string. You need to use the reference or you could use function in `re.sub` as well (depends on your case)

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
(\.\[[^][]*\])\s*
```

And replace this with `\1\n`, see [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/cduveH/1/).

---

This reads

```
(
    \.\[   # ".[" literally
    [^][]* # neither "[" nor "]" 0+ times
    \]     # "]" literally
)\s*       # consume whitespaces, eventually
```

Comment: The problem is that it also adds a new line after "[142]" even if there is no white space after [142] For e.g: it adds new line after [142] if the string is "Wikipedia.[142][152]"

Answer (score 1):

Use findall() to identify list of matching patterns. Then you can replace it with original string+'\n'